# Custom elements and :before :after

Tags: polymer, web-component, shadow-dom

In latest Chromium 37 I didn't succeed in using `:before` and `:after` on custom elements. Everything works in other browsers with Polymer Platform polyfill, but in Chromium with native support it doesn't.

Styling like this:

```
my-element:before {
    background : #000;
    content    : '';
    display    : block;
    height     : 10px;
    width      : 10px;
}
```

What did I missed here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your example works for me in Chrome 38: http://jsbin.com/lanatuhojowu/1/edit

Note: `:host::before` and `:host::after` not working is a bug in Chrome 37 (crbug.com/393509). This should hopefully make it out in the next version of Chrome (38), and is definitely in Chrome 39.

Comment: Thank you, I though that it might be bug, but didn't found any relevant.